# Can we use Microsoft Search Connectors as a result source for Classic search

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, microsoft-search

Is it possible to use connectors as one of the result sources in SharePoint online?

We create a new connector and we are able to configure that as  a  result source for Microsoft Search(modern search experience) in SharePoint online.

Is it  possible to add this as a result source in Classic search?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to use connectors as result source for classic search.